# How can I use SoapException Method on object of type Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, exception, polymorphism

I have a Method that get paramater of type - Exception

```
WriteException(Exception ex, int index, string s)
{
   // my code here...
}
```

sometimes the method gets an `Exception` object and sometimes `SoapException`
every time the exeption is of kind `SoapException` I want print: `ex.Detail.InnerText`
but if `ex` is of type `Exception`.
so after I recognize the type, how can I do `SoapException ex.Detail.InnerText`?

Comment: why not use two function overloads, one that has an Exception parameter and one that has a SoapException parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WriteException(Exception ex, int index, string s)
{
    var soapEx = ex as SoapException;

    if(null != soapEx)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(soapEx.Detail.InnerText);
      return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
```

another possible solution uses the `dynamic` keyword:

```
WriteException(Exception ex, int index, string s)
{
    dynamic soapEx = ex;

    Console.WriteLine(soapEx.Detail.InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
```